# The views are there but documents are missing

Tags: couchbase

I started getting errors on my laptop's installation several weeks ago (segmentation fault 11 when I did lookups on buckets, views worked fine). The database on my laptop and home computer are identical and I have a script I've used for months that backs-up data one one and restores to the other. When I started having problems on the laptop I thought it would be as easy as this to restore my database to a consistent state. Nope.

My grand hope then became that the new version of Couchbase 2.1.1 (from 2.0.1) might fix this problem. Nope. I then noticed in the Couchbase Console that all my buckets were being shown as an "amber" status:

[image]

Can someone help me understand what this means? My home computer's are all green and I'm assuming green is where I want to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the installation in your laptop, install the same version that you have in your home's computer and do an XDCR connection between your laptop an your home's computer to have an initial good state.

After that, delete the XDCR an re-try backups following the official instructions: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#backup-and-restore

I wish you luck.

Comment: I did delete and reinstall. Then used a couchbase backup and restore to achieve the same state as my home machine. Strangely the same problem occurred.

Comment: Have you tried to put your laptop as a XDCR of your home's? In fresh installation.